# Rails3 structure, engines, plugins, slices, gems, modules..?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins

Do you have a working example of a Rails3 mvc application?

How will it be organized?

I hope something like:

```
-app
--controller
--views
-plugins
--myapp1
---app
---controller
---views
---...
```

Can app1 use a model from app2?
Will "routes" file be deprecated?

reference:

https://web.archive.org/web/20170704120345/http://yehudakatz.com/2009/07/19/rails-3-the-great-decoupling

https://www.slideshare.net/jacobian/django-in-the-real-world-1750000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out the Rails 3 screencasts at http://rubyonrails.org/screencasts/rails3.  They're a great introduction to the structure of a Rails 3 app and how it's changed from Rails 2!

Answer (score 0):

Many of your questions will probably be answered in the [Rails 3 Release Notes](http://guides.rails.info/3_0_release_notes.html).

Answer (score -1):

Try "[Creating a weblog in 15 minutes with Rails 2](http://rubyonrails.org/screencasts)." Some of the code is outdated, but for the most part everything is still organized the same way.